# docker-compose cannot understand my env_file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, datastax

I am trying to start a Datastax cluster using docker-compose.

In order to avoid to repeat myself over the services, I've created a file with my environment variables, and I set the env_file property in my docker compose file.
Docker-compose is able to find the env file (when I put a wrong path it returned an error about the fact that the file doesn't exists), but still is not able to read the values I pun on it!

Here both my docker-compose and my env file.

[image]

As you can see, when I run "docker-compose up" in my PowerShell window, it doesn't work.

[image]

What am I missing?!?!

Here the details of the **docker-compose version** I am using

```
 docker-compose  version 1.8.0 
 build d988a55 docker-py version: 1.9.0
 CPython version: 2.7.11  
 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
```

And this is the **docker (for windows) version**

```
Client:
  Version:      1.12.1
  API version:  1.24
  Go version:   go1.6.3
  Git commit:   23cf638
  Built:        Thu Aug 18 17:52:38 2016
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
  Version:      1.12.1
  API version:  1.24
  Go version:   go1.6.3
  Git commit:   23cf638
  Built:        Thu Aug 18 17:52:38 2016
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Thanks

Comment: I did not try it on windows but on Unix you can't have spaces between your env var (e.g. CLUSTER_NAME) and "=" and the value. When I use spaces I get the error: `poorly formatted environment: variable 'xxx ' has white spaces.` This is another error than yours so I'm not sure. But you can give it a chance and edit your .env file and delete the spaces between vars and values.

Comment: Originally it was without spaces, and then I changed as my last desperate test to let it works. I also tried 
    variable:"xxx" 
but didn't work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing `env_file` with the `.env` file.

`env_file` provides environment variables to a container, but are not available to the Compose file

`.env` provides environment variables for use inside the Compose file

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Shoot, I think I see my misunderstand! So, what you are saying is that my "cluster.env" file should be named just ".env", and if I remove the env_file section everything should work like a charm? 
I'll give it a try tonight, but I am pretty confident it will works.